# 'Confirmation token is invalid' when testing with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cucumber, actionmailer

I'm trying to get a sign up form working with Devise; I'm testing it with Cucumber.

When a user signs up, I send a confirmation e-mail. Something goes wrong when running my test, though.

This is my scenario:

```
  Scenario: Signing in via confirmation
    Given there are the following users:
      | email             | password | unconfirmed |
      | user@ticketee.com | password | true        |
    And "user@ticketee.com" opens the email with subject "Confirmation instructions"
    And they click the first link in the email
    Then I should see "Your account was successfully confirmed."
    And I should see "Signed in as user@ticketee.com"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 expected there to be content "Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in." in "\n      Ticketee\n  \n\nTicketee\nSign up\n    Sign in\nResend confirmation instructions\n\n\n      \n      1 error prohibited this user from being saved:\n      Confirmation token is invalid\n\n\n  Email\n\n  \n\n  Sign inSign upForgot your password?" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I guess the important part here is:

`1 error prohibited this user from being saved:\n      Confirmation token is invalid`

I have tested this manually (went to sign up and clicked the confirmation link in the e-mail) and this works fine.. It's only when I test through Cucumber that I get the 'Confirmation token is invalid' message. Anyone know how I can fix this? I'd like to see my tests pass..

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Steps asked for in the comments:

```
When /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") opens? the email with subject "([^"]*?)"$/ do |address, subject|
  open_email(address, :with_subject => subject)
end
```

Clicking link:

```
When /^(?:I|they) click the first link in the email$/ do
  click_first_link_in_email
end
```

I just looked at the confirmation email I got and my e-mail address is parsed as a mailto: link; I changed the first link step to this:

`And they follow "Confirm my account" in the email`

but that didn't work either.. I'm still getting the invalid token error message.

Comment: Can you post the step definitions for the steps involving opening the email and clicking the link.

Comment: Ah, you're using the email_spec gem? Probably worth mentioning that too. I believe the generated email appears in the test.log, so check it there and see if has the correct link.

Comment: Oh; sorry for not mentioning that. I cleared my test.log and ran the tests.. It looks like it's sending the e-mail twice, but I'm not really sure. I could post the log here but it's rather big..

Comment: Here's the log:
http://pastebin.com/pzTPE1uJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So.. I wasted two hours on this. I had a typo.

I have the following line:

`unconfirmed = attributes.delete("unconfirmed") == "true"`

I forgot to put the quotes around `true`. Without the quotes, the test passes..

Jeez.

Thanks to everyone who put some time in helping me :)

Comment: Can you explain what that line is supposed to do? Perhaps there's a better to write it which is less error-prone. BTW, this should really have been caught by a unit test - a good example of why Cucumber alone is not sufficient.

Comment: This line is in my user_steps.rb; it sets the `unconfirmed` var for users, so I know which users have confirmed their acct and which haven't. I'm following a book though and the way the line is written isn't oh so clear to me but ya.. How would I write a unit test for that though? I'm kinda new to this whole TDD thing; I understand how to write Rspec tests for controllers etc, but for a steps file?

Comment: I have the ame problem but it doesn't pass with or without the quotes around true..any help?

Comment: I had done the same mistake while following the steps in [Rails 3 in action](http://www.manning.com/katz/) book. Thanks for adding the question & the answer here!